# Is there any delegate for monitoring progress when transfering data from WatchOs to iOs using WatchConnectivity?

Tags: ios, swift, watchos-2, watchconnectivity

I'm using WatchConnectivity to transfer files **from Apple Watch to iOS** device (this direction). Transfer itself is ok. I send file from Apple Watch by calling transfer file function:

```
session?.transferFile(url, metadata: metadata)
```

and I'm able to save a file on iOS device.
But I would like to show progress of transfer to the users on **iOS device**. For example user tap button "Download file" on iPhone and I would like to show some UI progress bar.
Is this possible? Because I found only this delegate which is called when transfer is done:

```
func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceive file: WCSessionFile) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `WCSessionFileTransfer` instance returned by

```
session?.transferFile(url, metadata: metadata)
```

has a `NSProgress *progress` property, you can use it to monitor the progress at Watch App w/ a `NSTimer` instance, and send live message (`WCSession-sendMessage:...`) to iPhone App to update related UI elements.

---

**Note**:

The `progress` is only available since iOS 12.0 & WatchOS 5.0.

```
API_AVAILABLE(ios(12.0), watchos(5.0))
```